# How does Jekyll treat posts in _posts/subdir

Tags: jekyll

The Jekyll Bootstrap project has a sample blog post in the directory `_posts/core-samples/` .

I assume, posts (files) in sub directories are handled the same way as posts in the root directory. Is this correct?

If so, I will add a "stage" sub directory, exclude it, so I can park posts and publish them by moving them.

Comment: The standard approach here would be to use the _drafts folder. But any folder that starts with an underscore or is excluded would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accidentally found it in the [post - yaml](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/#predefined-global-variables) section:

> Instead of placing posts inside of folders, you can specify one or
>   more categories that the post belongs to. When the site is generated
>   the post will act as though it had been set with these categories
>   normally. Categories (plural key) can be specified as a YAML list or a
>   space-separated string.

So **sub directories == categories**

Comment: As far as I can tell by testing, this is misleading. That is, subdirectories inside of _posts directories appear to be ignored (not turned into categories). Are you experiencing different behavior?

Comment: It been a while, cannot clarify this at the moment, but what I see is that in my github-website  I ended up with not using sub directories below _posts.

Comment: It's the other way around: the *parent* directory of `_posts` becomes a category. See https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1141#issuecomment-18363523

Comment: I just found this link which says, create top-level folders and put _posts into them. Then the top-levels become categories. https://miklb.com/blog/2016/04/26/organizing-jekyll-posts/

Answer (score 8):

As the different is only on `post.path` so I would agree to your statement:

> posts(files) in **sub directores** are handled the same way as posts in
>   the **root diretory**

You can park your posts in the directory `_posts/core-samples/` and publish them like this:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.path contains 'core-samples' %}
     ..your code
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

As a working sample you may see how [*this code*](https://github.com/chetabahana/chetabahana.github.io/blob/1329c5cc02f05384b603baf2e6bf051c52641b76/_includes/head/Eksekusi#L12) publish these [*parked posts*](https://github.com/chetabahana/chetabahana.github.io/tree/master/_posts/eksekusi) in [*their section*](https://chetabahana.github.io/#chetabahana-eksekusi).

Answer (score 6):

I ended up here because I wanted to create the following structure:

```
index.html
_animals
  cats
    my-cat.html
    ...
  dogs
    my-dog.html
    ...
```

I created that structure, then in `_config.yml`:

```
collections:
  animals:
    output: true
    permalink: /animal/:title.html
```

Finally, to get just the dogs in `index.html`:

```
<div id='dogs'>
  {% for a in site.animals %}
    {% if a.path contains 'dogs' %}
      <a href='{{ a.url }}'>{{ a.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

NB: that this approach requires that the directory containing all the records (`_animals` in my example) can't be named `_posts`, as the latter is a special name in Jekyll.

Answer (score 2):

Actually what that statement says is to put _posts folder inside a sub directory.
And then that sub directory will be treated as category.