# Jekyll how to write posts for different topics

Tags: jekyll

I am very new to jekyll. Currently, I noticed that there is only one `/_posts` folder in my project. All the posts I wrote in this folder will create a site in `/_site/posts`.

I wonder is there a way that I can write posts for different topics and generate the sites at different folders? For example, I want to write some posts related to 'travel', so I hope to put the markdown files in a folder like `/_travel`. I also want to write some posts related to 'work', so I hope to have a folder like `/_work`. And I hope jekyll can generate these websites separately, like `/_site/travel` and `/_site/work`.

The reason I want to solve this is I hope to create a path at the head of my posts. Currently, I am using

```
{% assign paths = page.url | split: '/' %}

{% for item in paths %}

    {% if forloop.first %}
      <span>
        <a href="{{ '/' | relative_url }}">
          {{ site.data.locales[site.lang].tabs.home | capitalize }}
        </a>
      </span>

    {% elsif forloop.last %}

      {% if page.collection == 'tabs' %}
        <span>{{ site.data.locales[site.lang].tabs[item] | default: page.title }}</span>
      {% else %}
        <span>{{ page.title }}</span>
      {% endif %}

    {% elsif %}
      <span>
        <a href="{{ item | relative_url }}">
          {{ site.data.locales[site.lang].tabs[item] | default: page.title }}
        </a>
      </span>
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
```

But apparently, all my work and travel posts are located in the same folder `_site/posts`

Comment: Collections are a good option. For posts, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15279405/3842598

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can create your own collections in `_config.yml`:

```
collections:
  travel:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:name
  work:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:name
```

`output: true` will render a page for each document in the collection.

Then you can create two folders named `_travel` and `_work` where you can put your posts.

You access the content of posts in each folder like this:

```
{% for travel_post in site.travel %}
  ...
  <p>{{ travel_post.content }}</p>
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Lastly, `permalink: /:collection/:name` should create a link at `/travel/name_of_post`. See [Permalinks for collections](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#collections) for a list of placeholders for the `permalink` configuration variable.